# How do I add Google Play Services to an AIDE project?

Tags: android, aide-ide

I develop solely in AIDE on my phone and tablet, and want to add Google Play Services.
Using this SDK Manager app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rebellos.sdkmanager) I can see Google Play Services rev. 22. Is there any way I can see if that is the latest?
Also, what do I do with my AIDE project to start using Google Play Services? Ie how to associate it with the Project etc etc.
My project is a GDX Game Project so has gdx-game and gdx-game-android folders, and while I'm totally happy with how all that works for the game, I'm unsure which one / how I get the downloaded Google Play Services in the project build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rebellos.sdkmanager&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dgoogle+play+services+in+aide&pcampaignid=APPU_1_rqOPVv3QGsKE-gH_iZ_oBA

It's an SDK manager for AIDE on Android!  :)